# Using a non-default keychain in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, keychain, codesign

How can I use a non-default keychain in Xcode iPhone project.

I have already tried '--keychain mycerts.keychain' in 'Other Code Signing Flags' in 'Code signing' build settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a long time of research, I concluded that it cannot be done.

Comment: I filed rdar://9273506 for this issue.

Comment: I agree, I spent days on it… the only way is to set the temp keychain as default for a while :/

Answer (score 7):

The codesign tool requires an **absolute path** to the keychain.

Use an additional "Run Script Build Phase" to call the codesign tool with the custom keychain. The embedded script should look like:

```
codesign -s 'your-identity' --keychain "${SRCROOT}/path/to/keychain" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"
```

[image]

Comment: A full path is only needed if the keychain is not in the default ~/Library/Keychains path

Answer (score 6):

in the Build setting under Code Signing -> Other code signing Flags, create a flag "--keychain keychain-name.keychain"

Answer (score 4):

While inconvenient, you can temporarily change your "default Keychain" to whichever keychain has your certificate/keys. XCode will then search that keychain during code-signing. You can do this via Keychain Access.app or the security(1) command-line utility. You're responsible for unlocking said keychain yourself, however.

Comment: Also, you can create a temporary keychain on the fly from command line, import your certificates/keys, set it as the default during compilation and code signing and then remove it, restoring your previous default keychain.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by setting the keychain search list to include your keychain:

```
security list-keychains -s login.keychain mycerts.keychain etc.keychain
```

To view the active keychain search list, use the same command without the -s param:

```
security list-keychains
```

A great link for reference is here: https://ss64.com/osx/security-keychain.html